# Using Anvil FileLoader to import users csv file into Colab notebook as dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, anvil, file-loader

I am trying to turn a Colab notebook into a web app. The notebook contains code that analyses a dataset. I have successfully managed to connect the notebook using:

```
!pip install anvil-uplink
import anvil.server
anvil.server.connect("<my uplink>")
```

Within anvil- I have successfully created a `FileLoader` component, allowing a user to upload their `csv` file, and a button which triggers a click event.

I am now stuck with how to code in anvil and within my Colab notebook in order to set the uploaded csv file as the df within the notebook for all successive analysis.

I'd really appreciate any help.

I have tried following Anvil tutorials and searching stackoverflow, and I am a beginner using anvil so I am particularly finding difficulty with what to code into the anvil code space.